# Access - Entering duplicate via form in Access show existing record

Tags: forms, ms-access, error-handling, duplicates

I'm building a form to add new serial ID's to my database.
We receive a paper, scan 2 barcodes and that's it. Sometimes we receive the same paper (with a little bit more or less information) and if we scan it we need to see when the first one was scanned so we don't have any doubles and can deceide which form to keep.

The database is build like this.

**Serial ID (barcode) | Specification ID (barcode) | Date**

So my question is:

Can I display a warning message when scanning the code and show when the already existing form was scanned?
I've been tinkering with "BeforeUpdate" but I can't seem to get it to work (still a novice at this but slowly learning.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your BeforeUpdate code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies!

I figured out how the VBA code should be, for anyone with the same problem check it out:

```
Dim SID As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim rsc As DAO.Recordset
Set rsc = Me.RecordsetClone
SID = Me.BloedeenheidID.Value
stLinkCriteria = "[BloedeenheidID]=" & "'" & SID & "'"
'Check ScannedForms table for duplicate BloedeenheidID number
If DCount("BloedeenheidID", "ScannedForms", _
stLinkCriteria) > 0 Then
'Undo duplicate entry
Me.Undo
'Message box warning of duplication
MsgBox "Warning! The ID number " _
& SID & " has already been entered." _
& vbCr & vbCr & "You will now been taken to the record.", _
vbInformation, "Duplicate Information"
'Go to record of original BloedeenheidID
rsc.FindFirst stLinkCriteria
Me.Bookmark = rsc.Bookmark
End If
Set rsc = Nothing
End Sub
```